# Norm of ideal is an element of the ideal (proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

There is a lemma in my lecture notes that states

> **Lemma.** Let $K$ be a number field and let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a non-zero ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$. Let $A = \mathrm{Norm}(\mathfrak{a})$. Then $A \in \mathfrak{a}$.
>
> *Proof*. By definition, $A = \mathrm{Norm}(\mathfrak{a}) = \#\mathcal{O}_{K}/\mathfrak{a}$. By Lagrange's Theorem, $A \cdot (1 + \mathfrak{a}) = 0 + \mathfrak{a}$ in $\mathcal{O}_{K}/\mathfrak{a}$. Thus $A \in \mathfrak{a}$.$\hspace{295pt}\square$

I'm not sure how Lagrange's Theorem is being used here.

I know that $\mathcal{O}_{K}/\mathfrak{a}$ is the set of additive cosets of $\mathfrak{a}$, so that
$$
\mathcal{O}_{K}/\mathfrak{a} = \left\{ \mathfrak{a}, 1 + \mathfrak{a}, \ldots, r + \mathfrak{a} \right\}
$$
which has $A$ elements in it, each of which have the same size. I thought that $\mathfrak{a} = 0 + \mathfrak{a}$ since $0$ is the additive identity, but I'm not sure why we multiply $A$ by the ideal coset $(1 + \mathfrak{a})$, nor why that equals $0 + \mathfrak{a}$, nor why this implies that $A \in \mathfrak{a}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lagrange's theorem says that, if $g\in G$, a group, then $g^{|G|}=e$, right? In additive notation, this is written: $|G|\cdot g = 0$.

Thus, take for $g$ the coset $(1+\mathfrak{a})$, which is an element of the quotient ring, which is an additive group. Then for $|G|$, we have $A$, and the result is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But for what reason is $A \in \mathfrak{a}$ after this? Would it be appropriate to, say, expand the left hand side so that we have $A(1 + \mathfrak{a}) = A + A\mathfrak{a} = 0 + \mathfrak{a}$, so $A = 0$ (since this is the order of the quotient ring) and then $A\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{a}$ implies $A \in \mathfrak{a}$?

Comment: Remember how coset multiplication works. We have $A(1+\mathfrak{a})=(A+\mathfrak{a})$, not $(A+A\mathfrak{a})$. If $(A+\mathfrak{a})=(0+\mathfrak{a})$, that means that $A\in\mathfrak{a}$, because the zero coset *is* the ideal.

Comment: Ah perfect, I was just forgetting simple things. This clears it all up, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Lagrange’s theorem tells you that the order of any subgroup divides the order of the group. In particular, the order of any element of the group divides the order of the group. Hence, $A=n\cdot d$ for some $d$, where $n$ is the order of $1 + \mathfrak{a}$. Thus,

$$A(1+ \mathfrak a) = d(n(1 + \mathfrak a)) = d(0 + \mathfrak a) = 0 + \mathfrak a$$